# Secure sync of TrueCrypt containers 

Tags: backup, truecrypt

Need to sync arbitrary files within two TrueCrypt containers; one container is a backup, the other the one actively used by me, both are local during the transaction.

Current concern security wise is that there would be "data leaks" that would result from the sync tool being used; for example, the sync tool producing indexes that when be stored unencrypted on disk.

Any suggestions, or insights into the possible attack vectors that might result from using a sync tool as described?

**UPDATE:** I've removed the reference to "on Windows", since while the answers, and question they addressed deal with Windows, these answers (putting aside the sync tools used) apply to Windows, Linux, OSX, etc -- and I would not want the person reading the title of the question to believe the question only applies to Windows, since it does not, and given the importance of securely executing backups of encrypted data, I thought it best to make the question as accessible as possible.

Comment: Just to clarify: You want to sync files from inside one tcc to another? Or do you want to sync arbitrary files to two tcc? Both would mean that you have to mount both container at the same time.

Comment: I'm confused why you think my answer is off topic. You state "Need to sync arbitrary files within two TrueCrypt container". So you are talking about syncing files within mounted containers. I talked about a security issue about backups on truecrypt container AND reference a page on the truecrypt site. I don't know how it doesn't answer your question. You asked about leaks and i told you about seeing which part of the sector change and that it could be used as an attack.

Comment: Oh you're not asking about security issues when making backups via sync, you're asking about security leaks from sync tools when making backups. I'll make a quit edit. (edit 2)

Comment: why did you -1 me anyways?

Comment: @acidzombie24: The current -1 on your answer is not from me, I removed my -1 and the related comment about your answer not being an answer after your edit, though within a short time after someone else gave it a -1. Just gave your answer a +1 to counter the -1.

Comment: thanks :D. FYI i used robocopy yesterday and the cmds i used were `robocopy src dst /S (recuse into subdirs) /W:1 (wait=1sec, in case of error) /R:1 (retry once in case of error)`. It copied w/o deleting files in dst directory. It creates no indexes or anything you worry about in this question. Copying no file attributes (like ACL) except for the time modified information.

Comment: You should also be aware that diffs between truecrypt containers over time can leak information about the underlying contents. The mode of encryption truecrypt uses, called xts, leaks like crazy in this circumstance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Current concern security wise is that there would be "data leaks" that would result from the sync tool being used; for example, the sync tool producing indexes that when be stored unencrypted on disk.

You are correct to believe there is a risk of data leaking as a result of indexes. How much of a risk that is depends on *what* exactly is indexed.

A while ago, I lead a project to build something a little like dropbox. To compare directories across runs, we used the path name, a sha256 hash of the contents if not already computed, various timestamp information etc.

Clearly, if a sync tool were to store this information about files stored in an encrypted container, the attacker would also have access to them. The exact risk of that really depends on your given scenario.

I suspect, however, there are bigger risks in play than you think. Let's assume, for example, that on opening a file, your innocent piece of software creates a *copy* so as to not corrupt the individual - however, you've mounted the file system read-only, so it handily creates a copy of the file in your temp folder. Great, except - it just copied your data from an encrypted partition to an unencrypted one, thereby leaking it.

The same could be true of sync tools. This would be a fairly bad way to build one - but it is conceivable the tool could copy files to a temporary location in progress. Again, you have a leak problem.

To be a bit more realistic - let's assume the sync tool copies the files in memory by `mmap`ing them and copying between them. What if you experience a system crash during this update and your app happens to be core dumped? Heck, what happens if the truecrypt drivers' memory is core dumped too? It might well contain unencrypted file data.

The fact of the matter is you're unlikely to be able to deduce the contents of entire files from any of these scenarios - but like getting damp in your house, *something* will leak, somewhere. The only way to be totally sure you have everything wrapped up is to do the obvious: encrypt the *whole lot*. Swap, disk, everything.

So to answer the question you asked: an attacker can clean whatever the sync tool stores. Have a look. Grab [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645), see where it is storing data and then look at what's in it. That'll tell you exactly what data is being leaked.

To answer the question you didn't ask: there's no way to be **absolutely** certain you are not going to leak something using a truecrypt container on an unencrypted system.

Answer (score 6):

The question is now "how can I do file level synchronization between two open TrueCrypt containers on a single host without any local leakage of data from the sync tool?".

The answer is you probably can't - certainly none of the well established file sync tools (unison, rsync, SyncToy, etc.) promise not to have such leaks. Their focus is purely on being efficient and reliable.

This is presumably because doing so would involve a lot of very hard work to support an obscure use case.  Firstly, if someone can get close enough to your machine to take advantage of this sort of leakage, then you have worse problems. And secondly, if you really need to control for this vulnerability, then there are a couple of steps you can take that work regardless of the sync tool used:

- use full disk encryption so any leaks are also encrypted.
- sync closed volumes, eliminating all sync tool leakage at the cost of performance.

Note: I specify *sync-tool* leakage here since there are other sorts of leaks: differential analysis of the containers, or leaks from the tools you use to manipulate the contents of container once open. But again, if the attacker has compromised the machine enough to perform these attacks, then you have worse problems. Why do a difficult differential analysis of container changes when you can just replace the TrueCrypt binary with something that emails the contents of the container to you?

(One last point: there are many good open source tools for file syncing, so a third alternative is to fork them into your own super-secure version.)

Comment: **Main thing** thing I want to point out is the question is really about if SyncToy would have data leaks that would make the TrueCrypt container, and if so, if there's anyway to prevent them. Mainly the issue that came to mind is that SyncToy works by creating indexes that might contain among other info: filenames, change-timestamps, etc.  Make sense? Again, thanks!

Comment: @blunders If you're just using SyncToy to copy the container files, then you have practically no risk of leakage.  If you're actually opening the containers, and using SyncToy to copy data between them, then you would stand the risk of leakage like the ones you are suggesting.  Whether SyncToy *actually* handles data in the manner you're suggesting (indexes, etc) may be a better question for [su].

Comment: @Iszi: The sync is of the contents of the containers, not the containers. As for asking on Super User, this question is about how to do a secure sync of the contents of two local TrueCrypt containers, and though SyncToy is given as one option to do the sync, all that matters to me is the sync is secure, fast, and reliable; though unless the process is secure, being fast and reliable is not important.

Comment: @blunders The only 100% secure & reliable way would be a sync of the container files themselves.  However, this presumes that only one of the containers has any newer data, and it's not going to be any faster than a manual copy of the entire container file.  Any other solution is likely to be as insecure as SyncToy when handling opened containers unless there is some software that specifically makes a point to securely destroy its indexing data after each sync.

Comment: @blunders  And, again, whether or not indexing or other metadata is actually generated or left behind by SyncToy (or others) is probably something that should be asked elsewhere - although it is important to know in evaluating the security of the tool.

Comment: @Iszi: Understand your points, though the question is about how to securely get this done, not how a given tool works. One thought I've had is to have a third container that stores the index files, find a sync tool that would allow me to define the store path of the "sync data", mount the three containers, and do the sync; seems like at that point the only risk security wise would be the files being accessible for the time the containers are unlocked. Does that help explain why I see this are a question about security? Not trying to debate the subject, just don't see this as a super user Q&A.

Comment: We use DFS-R to sync files at rest, as a container file is a file at rest.  A quick search for "sharing violation" errors in the DFS-R log reveals nothing.  Due to the way file containers work (can only be mounted in one location, I believe), you will not run into replicating the file as on the receiver, the file will not be in use; unless it is in fact, in use.  But then you have another "thread safe" like issue to solve with your "shared" file containers.

Comment: +1 @mbrownnyc: Thanks, though unless I'm mistaken, it appears you're suggesting to replicate the unmounted container encrypted, though the point is to mount the main container and it's backup container, then do a file sync within them. As mentioned in a [comment above](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/14196/secure-sync-of-truecrypt-containers-on-windows/14200#comment22262_14200) appears the solution is to find a sync tool that allows the path for the sync profile config/index/etc, and have that path resolve to the 3rd container just for that data. Am I missing something? Thanks!

Comment: DFS-R has cache locations (that could be encrypted).  But it has a DB that really can't be encrypted.  The lightest way is to use a dedicated synchronization mechanism.  Your question is two parted (clearly).  There are many "self-contained" replication options that will work for you, `rsync` being one off the top of my head.  Dupe the last dupe and then run `rsync` between the copy of that last dupe and the live data.  I think `SyncToy` might work in a similar manner.  And I'm unsure if it uses an [ESE](http://www.woanware.co.uk/?page_id=89).

Comment: @Iszi "The only 100% secure & reliable way would be a sync of the container files themselves" <--- wtf!?! no. See my answer.

Comment: @acidzombie24 I'm not sure where you're getting the idea that syncing two open containers is more secure than (or, at least, as secure as) syncing two closed containers.  In the former case, the data is at *least* vulnerable during memory transfers, never mind the possibility that it could end up in the swap file or temporary (or permanent) indexes.  In the latter case, the sync tool has no access to the cleartext data, therefore it poses no risk to the confidentiality of the data during or after sync.

Comment: @Iszi: The issue is seeing how the backup is different from the current copy. This truecrypt seems to agree with me. http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=how-to-back-up-securely If mounting a backup 'might' be a problem than mounting for normal use is a problem thus using truecrypt is pointless. However i dont think that is the case (make sure there are no keyloggers!) so i'm sure mounting two (different) containers (as the doc suggest themselves) are fine and a good idea

Comment: @Graham Hill: acidzombie24 is correct, though more importantly at this point, why do you believe your answer above answers the question?

Comment: @Iszi also what happens when you don't finish the sync and for one reason or another you can't continue it at that moment. What if your main container goes down. The backup would be in an invalid state. The file system would be corrupted and if you are really unlucky it corrupted part is an important directory block (or the root directory block) which means you cant access into any files in that folder. Its not a safe way to make backups

Comment: @blunders 'cos it does, even after all your edits. Why do you think it doesn't?

Comment: @Graham Hill: Thanks for asking, I really should have stated why. So, guessing you've read acidzombie24 comments/answer, and are aware of ciphertext block attacks, which in fact were one of the main reasons I'd thought to ask the question; though oddly hadn't forgot the issue related to serial versioning of a container; which since I don't do, wasn't an issue for me anyway. Point is that unless I'm missing something, your answer appears to be an insecure way to do TrueCrypt container backups, and does not provide a way to sync arbitrary files within two TrueCrypt containers.

Comment: @Graham Hill: Confused, though am impressed with your effort. So, the suggestion to "sync closed volumes, eliminating all leakage at the cost of performance" would not evade analysis of "[which sectors of the volumes are changing over time](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=how-to-back-up-securely)", right, or am I missing something? Also, just a heads up that if you do an update, and don't ping/comment @ me, then I have no idea you updated the answer; randomly stopped back by, and noticed the update.

Comment: @blunders That's not a sync tool leak, it's a leak from the underlying concept of "I am changing the backup container over time". Such a leak is unavoidable in this scenario, even if you follow TrueCrypt's advice to destroy and recreate the backup each time, since the attacker can see the original TrueCrypt container as well as the backup.

Comment: @Graham Hill: No, it's not the same thing. TrueCrypt ciphertext blocks would be comparable if you version the same container, they would not be if a new container is created each time.

Comment: @blunders I didn't say the vulnerabilty wasn't real. I said that it is *irrelevant in the scenario you posit* because a) even if you fix it as per Truecrypts advice and recreate the backup container every time you backup, the attacker can exploit the vulnerability *against the original container* and b) there is no scenario where the attacker can exploit this vulnerability that does not also allow the attacker to get all your data in a thousand other simpler ways. **You're worrying if your window locks are sufficiently pick resistant when your front door is wide open.**

Answer (score 0):

IMO the easiest and fastest way to sync is mounting two containers and using your favorite tool to sync them (i kind of like robocopy). When you have a backup use a DIFFERENT container. If one container is a copy of another than someone who gets access to both can look at the sectors that change and use that information.

If you make two containers than that wont be an issue because everything would be different regardless if the same files in the same places are in there.

I don't know which 'sync tool' you may use but if it isn't storing temporary information (say your local temp area) while syncing you should be fine. Some people think you should disable virtual memory when using encryption but IMO that isn't required and just paranoia.

-edit- If your backup can be accessed by someone repeatedly (instead of just the current and backup the above assumes) you may consider making a new container each time and copying all the data as recommended by truecrypt http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=how-to-back-up-securely

-edit2- It now appears you are asking about leaks when using tools. You didn't mention any tools so i can't comment much. As long as the tool doesn't make temporary files when copying or has a db/information outside of the container (sometime it is in the users app data directory) than you should be fine. As i mention above i like robocopy which is simply an advance command like file copy program. See http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html I personally don't copy attibute data nor want files deleted in the remote volume. I think i normally use `robocopy srcDriveOrFolder dst /S /W:1 /R:1`